# Store JSON to oracle DB

Tags: php, json, oracle

When i hit my PHP script in my VPS, i got json response
I send my json response to my local PC and then from local PC send it again to oracle database in my VPN server. But somehow it failed. I search everywhere and can't find what the cause of the failed

here is my php script

```
<?php

/*Include*/
include("wablas.php"); //includewablas api

/*Fetching JSON*/
$str_data = file_get_contents("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/passer.php");
$data = json_decode($str_data, true);

/*Kirim WA melalui API WA BLAS untuk tiap data*/
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($data["data"]); $i++)
{
    $wa = new wablas();
    $wa->kirim_wa($data["data"][$i]["NoHP"],"test"); 
}
?>
```

xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is my local PC IP

here is my wablas.php script that response and encode json

```
    function kirim_wa($phone,$message)
    {

        $curl = curl_init();
        $data = [
            'phone' => $phone,
            'message' => $message,
        ];

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
            array(
                "Authorization: ".$this->token,
            )
        );
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://selo.wablas.com/api/send-message");
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        $result = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($result);
        echo json_encode($result); //add on
    }
```

and here is my script in local PC use for pass the json from wablas.php to my oracle table/database in my VPN server

```
<?php

/*Import Database Connection*/
require_once('connection.php');

/*Variable Initialization*/
$datalog = array();

/*Fetching JSON*/
$str_datalog = file_get_contents("http://yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy/wablast/kirimwa.php");
$array = json_decode($str_datalog, true);

/*Push to Array*/
$status = $array['status'];
$message = $array['message'];
$data_array = $array['data'];
$message_array = $data_array['message'];
$quota = $data_array['quota'];
$message_id = $message_array[0]['id'];
$message_phone = $message_array[0]['phone'];
$message_text = $message_array[0]['text'];
$message_status = $message_array[0]['status'];

/*Query*/
$querylog = "INSERT INTO SMS_WABLAST (IDWA, NO_TUJUAN, MSGTXT, SUCCESS ) VALUES ('$message_id','$message_phone','$message_text','$status')";

/*Push to Dbase*/
$s = oci_parse($conn,$querylog);
oci_execute($s);

/*Close Oracle Connection*/
oci_close($conn);
```

yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy is my VPS server IP

Comment: What do you mean "failed"? Did you get an error? Was the data saved to Oracle somehow not what you expected?

Comment: the data not saved to oracle and I don't get any error

Comment: (i) add [error checking](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-error.php) to your code (ii) update your post with the DB column datatypes (iii) give an example of the string or JSON you are trying to insert (iv) give the DB and Oracle client versions (because Oracle JSON handling has been rapidly getting more features)

Comment: Okay will do update it